# Formato de fecha en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

tengo actualmente este formato para mi fecha `%B %d, %Y` el cual me retorna `martes mayo 15, 2018` pero quisiera modificarlo para que me retornara este formato martes 26 de agosto y que a su vez funcione en con i18n.

actualmente tengo esta: `%A %d de %B` pero necesito que me funcione con otros i18n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que te funcione con otros idiomas en `I18n`, necesitas crear los archivos *locale* correspondientes; por ejemplo, este sería para español:

```
# config/locales/es.yml

es:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%A %d de %B"
    month_names: [~, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Ene, Feb, Mar, Abr, May, Jun, Jul, Ago, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dic]
    day_names: [Domingo, Lunes, Martes, Miércoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sábado]
```

Y lo utilizarías con el método `I18n.l`; ejemplo en consola y *default locale* en inglés:

```
fecha = Date.new(2018,5,15)
#=> Tue, 15 May 2018

I18n.l(fecha, locale: :es)
#=> "Martes 15 de Mayo"
```

Si quieres agregar más, simplemente agrega una nueva llave en `formats`; por ejemplo:

```
# config/locales/es.yml

es:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      long: "%A %d de %B"
    month_names: [~, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Ene, Feb, Mar, Abr, May, Jun, Jul, Ago, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dic]
    day_names: [Domingo, Lunes, Martes, Miércoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sábado]
```

Y para utilizarlo debes indicar indicar el formato:

```
fecha = Date.new(2018,5,15)
#=> Tue, 15 May 2018

I18n.l(fecha, locale: :es)
#=> "2018-05-15"

I18n.l(fecha, locale: :es, format: :long)
#=> "Martes 15 de Mayo"
```

En la vista puedes utilizar únicamente `l` (sin necesidad de indicar `locale`):

```
<%= l @fecha %>
<%= l @fecha, format: :long %>
```

Para agregar más *locales* (idiomas), debes generar nuevos archivos con las traducciones de cada idioma especificando la traducción para el formato de fecha que necesites (`long` en el último ejemplo).

Por ejemplo, si quisieras agregar italiano, podrías generar el siguiente archivo en *config/locales/*:

```
# config/locales/it.yml

it:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      long: "%A %d %B"
    month_names: [~, Gennaio, Febbraio, Marzo, Aprile, Maggio, Giugno, Luglio, Agosto, Settembre, Ottobre, Novembre, Dicembre]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Gen, Feb, Mar, Apr, Mag, Giu, Lug, Ago, Set, Ott, Nov, Dic]
    day_names: [Domenica, Lunedì, Martedì, Mercoledì, Giovedì, Venerdì, Sabato]
```

Y para utilizarlo:

```
fecha = Date.new(2018,5,15)
#=> "2018-05-15"

I18n.l(fecha, locale: :it, format: :long)
#=> "Martedì 15 Maggio"
```

Comment: esta fue la forma correcta, lo único diferente fue que lo agregue en Time format de los locales, muchas gracias Gerry.